# «O primeiro e segundo classificado» ou «o primeiro e segundo classificados»?

Tags: concordância, número-gramatical

Na busca do Google, *classificado* vence *classificados* pela estreita margem de 4 a 3. Portanto como é que é?

> (a) Sujeito: *O primeiro e segundo classificado(s?) defrontam-se este fim de semana.*
>
> (b) Objeto: *Vamos ver o primeiro e segundo classificado(s?) este fim de semana.*
>
> (c) Sei lá: *Vamos ver o jogo entre o primeiro e segundo classificado(s?) este fim de semana.*
>
> (d) Aposto: *FCX e FCY, o primeiro e segundo classificado(s?), defrontam-se este fim de semana*.

Mas se fosse *casas* em vez de *classificados*, eu iria definitivamente para o singular (imaginem que andamos a ver casas para comprar:

> A primeira e a segunda casa são muito espaçosas, etc.

Portanto, *primeiro e segundo* vem seguido de nome singular ou plural? Ou depende do nome?

Comment: Eu acho que depende do determinante, se for "o primeiro e **o** segundo **classificado**", se for "o primeiro e segundo **classificados**".

Comment: Então, vamos a estudar isso, e dá-me um resposta!

Comment: Jacinto agora estou sem tempo, quando puder respondo.

Comment: Não devias ter dito `Portanto, primeiro e segundo vêm seguidos de nome singular ou plural?`? :p

Comment: @ANeves Vou aceitar provisoriamente a sugestão, e penso entretanto se abro ou não uma pergunta sobre o assunto. Olha, que pensando bem, talvez se justifique.

Comment: Ups, estava a *tentar* fazer uma brincadeira! Como se assumisse que só uma das opções da pergunta fosse válida, e fizesse uma correção ao texto da pergunta baseada nessa assunção.

Comment: @ANeves Acho que aqui a questão é diferente: pensar *[o conjunto] 'primeiro e segundo'* vem seguido ou *[os termos] primeiro e segundo* vêm seguidos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com [esta página](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-em-estrutura-de-coordenacao-2-adjectivos--1-nome/19428) e [esta outra](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/substantivo-no-plural-depois-de-adjetivos-numerais-coordenados/33648), qualquer uma das formas está correcta.

Quando usamos

> O primeiro e segundo classificado(s)...
>   A primeira e a segunda casa(s)...

o que acontece é "a elisão, ou a não-repetição, d[o nome], núcleo de um dos grupos nominais que estão a ser ligados"<sup>[1](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-em-estrutura-de-coordenacao-2-adjectivos--1-nome/19428)</sup>, "podendo [o artigo definido] repetir-se ou não em associação com o segundo ordinal".<sup>[2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/substantivo-no-plural-depois-de-adjetivos-numerais-coordenados/33648)</sup> Claudionor Aparecido Ritondale diz ainda, em [*Português: Sintaxe Avançada* (São Paulo, 2009, p. 182)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-FdGBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA363&ots=G3O43WdtlN&dq=Portugu%C3%AAs%3A%20Sintaxe%20Avan%C3%A7ada&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q&f=false), que:

> No caso de numerais ordinais que se referem a um único substantivo, podem ser usadas as seguintes construções: *Falei com os moradores do primeiro e segundo andar / (...) do primeiro e segundo andares*.

Pode ainda dizer-se

> Os primeiro e segundo classificados...
>   As primeira e segunda casas...

uma vez que os dois adjectivos, primeiro/a e segundo/a, impõem "uma concordância plural a um nome e ao seu determinante.<sup>[1](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-em-estrutura-de-coordenacao-2-adjectivos--1-nome/19428)</sup>" Esta variação é, no entanto, mais comum com adjectivos pospostos, como

> os ciclos arturiano e wagneriano<sup>[2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/substantivo-no-plural-depois-de-adjetivos-numerais-coordenados/33648)</sup>

O segundo artigo menciona ainda que se nota "preferência pelo artigo definido singular antes do primeiro ordinal."<sup>[2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/substantivo-no-plural-depois-de-adjetivos-numerais-coordenados/33648)</sup>

Comment: Muito interessante. Mas eu não me consigo obrigar a dizer *a primeira e segunda casas*, embora não tenha grande problema com os outros exemplos. Serei só eu?

Comment: Talvez. Eu tenho mais dificuldade em fazer _as primeira e segunda casas_ soar bem na minha cabeça :P Mas aparentemente estão todas certas.

Comment: Absolutamente: *as primeira e segunda*, nem à lei da bala.